# AWS web server refused to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "random" {}

resource "random_pet" "name" {}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0022f774911c1d690"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data     = file("init-script.sh")
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.web-sg.id]

  tags = {
    Name = random_pet.name.id
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "web-sg" {
  name = "${random_pet.name.id}-sg"
  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  } 
  
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

I am using Terraform to deploy a PHP web server. As shown, *ingress* and *egress* rules are defined and I should be able to connect. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I am following this tutorial:

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource?in=terraform/configuration-language

Comment: Looks like this example is assuming that you are deploying into an existing VPC the route table of which has a route to an internet gateway. Is that the case for you?

Comment: How are you connecting? Have you done `terraform output application-url`?

Comment: @Paolo I am deploying to the default AWS VPC

Comment: @PySquirrel and does the route table associated to the VPC have a route to an internet gateway?

Comment: @baduker "application-url = "ec2-3-82-38-246.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php" yes, I am connecting to this URL, still "ec2-3-82-38-246.compute-1.amazonaws.com refused to connect."

Comment: @Paolo the OP is using the default VPC so there's a route to IG.

Comment: @baduker that's not necessarily true; OP or someone else in his account might have removed that route for whatever reason

Comment: @Paolo I am the only one using the acc, still I have route table and acl associated

Comment: just launched another instance through the console and connected to it, still can't connect to the first one

Comment: Some stupid guesses here. Make sure you are connecting to `http://ec2-3-82-38-246.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.php`. Chrome likes to use `https` by default, which you didn't have set up.  If this is not the case, you may want to make sure that the init-script executed correctly. You should connect to your instance and check the httpd is serving something.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I am using Opera, however Chromium based, uses http (80). However, I also opened 443 just to test if I could connect through the console at all, but doesn't work. I think something in the terraform config is causing the problem...

Comment: Verify it's in a public subnet, not private. 
Add an SSH rule to the security group so you can SSH in and look at the services running and what's listening on port 80, for example; `lsof -i :80` If it's a default linux ami you should be able to use SSM to connect instead of SSH (even through the console) regardless of what subnet it's in.
If your web service (nginx or apache) isn't in the startup services, that could be 1 reason you're not able to connect although I see it should be based on the init-script.

Comment: @paulg both instances are in the same VPC, same subnet, even in the same AZs, inbound and outbound rules are the same, can't really figure out what's exactly happening... SSM is not installed on both and can't use it

Comment: What do you mean by "refused to connect"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned and ran this tutorial myself & it does not work for me either. Trying to connect gives me a timeout error.

**1st observation** - it's very old & not a great tutorial. The AMI it samples does not even exist anymore & I used the latest AMZN Default Linux 2 AMI instead.

**2nd observation** - no key pair is created or used with this EC2 Instance in the tutorial which makes troubleshooting difficult since you cannot connect & view logs.

**3rd observation** - ties in with my 1st one, `chkconfig` is used in the init-script & if you're using a newer AMI (centos, redhat or amzn linux image) they all likely use `systemctl` instead.

**Conclusion:** This tutorial really needs updating & I don't recommend using it since it's virtually unusable and very outdated.